# Opengl пиксельные координаты

Tags: c++, c, opengl, 2d, текстура

Пишу 2D игру на OpenGL. Все прекрасно, никаких там GLUT, только вот одно не могу понять как сделать: Например, мне нужно нарисовать картинку с пиксельными координатами. Например:

```
x = 1
y = 100
w = 20
h = 300
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ура! Нашел вот что: https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm
Нужно было применять не glOrtho а gluOrtho2D.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо знать как у вас настроена камера (какую область "мира" она видит) и проекция (как она преобразует видимое в пиксели на экране).

Обычно достаточно "единичной" камеры (матрица без трансформаций) и ортографической проекции, например, `glOrtho` с размерами соответствующими области на экране в которую рисуете. Дальше разберетесь.